# Change variable in Layout from view script

Tags: zend-framework, layout

in my layout i have things like meta tags etc. that may change in e.g. in different static sites.

Example:
if i go to
/static/about
i would like to have a different meta-description as in
/static/contact

My Problem is that i would like to change these variables/values inside the view script static/content/about or static/content/contact and NOT in the controller.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the view helper: [PlaceHolders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.view.placeholders.conclusion.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post may it useful for u :
http://blog.ggshow.com/index.php/reference/zend-framework-view-helper-placeholder